# Database design for storing text inputs that also support autocomplete

Tags: database-design

I am designing a system that allows users to specify items to which they are allergic.  As they begin tying in each allergen into a text field, I intend to provide autocomplete-style suggestions so that they can either pick from one of the suggestions or finish typing in the allergen on their own.  The list of suggestions will come from a lookup table that will only include the most common allergens.

I have no problems with providing the suggestions from the lookup table but I'm trying to figure out the best way to save associated allergens in the database where those allergens can be either something that's already in the lookup table or something that is custom to the user (and will not be added to the lookup table).  I can think of two possible solutions but neither of them seems perfect.

Option 1 stores each user allergen as text as in:
user: id, name
allergen_lookup: name
user_allergies: user_id, allergen

In this case, there is no relationship between the allergen_lookup and user_allergies tables and user_allergies.allergen is a text field.  The problem with this essentially comes down to (a lack of) normalization but at least it supports custom allergens without requiring additional tables.

Option 2 uses an extra table to store the custom allergens as in:
user: id, name
allergen_lookup: id, name
user_allergies: user_id, allergen_id
user_custom_allergies: user_id, custom_allergy

In this case, user_allergies.allergen_id links to allergen_lookup.id.  The user_allergens table is used to store associations between users and known allergens (from the lookup table) and user_custom_allergies table is used to track the unknown allergens (those not in the lookup table).  The problem with this is the use of two tables to essentially track the same kind of information (user allergens).

So, I apologize for the long-winded description but any suggestions on how best to store this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You may be overcomplicating it, but tell me if I am not hitting the question asked.

How I would approach this:

I would have a user,userAllergies and allergies table - userAllergies being the intersection table.

This would allow you to display all the allergies that the database currently has stored to the user when they are typing. This also will allow you to have a normalised database where data is not repeated. this is because the intersection table will allow you to associate allergy with a user, without interfering with the allergy table.

Just some advice for the future. Use the normal form procedure to break dow your database problem. it will help you determine the structure of your database and the best approach to take.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works if I was willing to add user-provided allergens to the allergies table but I would prefer not to do that. I want the allergies table, and by extension the autocorrect suggestions, to only include those allergens that I have approved. Otherwise, I may end up with "peanuts", "peanut" and "pnuts" as suggestions. I would prefer to only offer "peanuts" and "tree nuts", etc. in the allergies table and find some other place to store whatever custom allergen the user types in.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest that you manually add all of the most common allergies that a person could have. Then, show these most common allergies to the user when they are searching for their allergy. However, if they have an allergy that does not exist in the database, they can make a request to have it added. If you have an admin section within your application, you could allow them to add the allergies that the user has requested. The problem with your idea is that it will create an inefficient database with data that is different throughout. Therefore, creating a slow database.

Comment: You should just add the allergies that are most common as I have said. Then provide functionality where the users can request their allergy be added if it is not available. this will ensure the database design will be functional.

Comment: The problem with allowing users to add an allergy is that they could spell it wrong. For example, you have added "Peanut" but many other users have added "Penut". This will return two results, which in turn showcases bad application and database design.

Comment: Again, thanks. The problem with requiring users to request additions to the DB is that it makes for a poor user experience which can oftentimes be at odds with the optimal DB design. I think we will likely go with a 3rd option where any "new" allergen added by the user gets added to the allergen table but is flagged as only being available/shown to that user. It means that the allergen table could grow bigger than optimal but it provides a better user experience. On the admin side, we'll also build the ability to approve the custom allergen if it is valid or to correct it if it is not.